# Thread Count is too high-what can I do in short term?

Tags: sql-server, cpu

Before I posted this question read following articles.

- [Max. Worker Threads and when you should change it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsakthi/2011/03/13/max-worker-threads-and-when-you-should-change-it/) by Sakthivel Chidambaram
- [Are my actual worker threads exceeding the sp_configure 'max worker threads' value?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Premier-Field-Engineering/Are-my-actual-worker-threads-exceeding-the-sp-configure-max/ba-p/370506?collapse_discussion=true&q=worker%20thread%20maxdop&search_type=thread) by Tom Stringer
- [How do you measure CPU pressure?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2005/09/05/how-do-you-measure-cpu-pressure/) by Thomasda
- [SQLOS’s DMVs Continue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slavao/2006/09/28/sqloss-dmvs-continue/) by Slavao

I am familiar with investigating high thread count issue by looking at following items (not comprehensive):

- Maxdop setting
- Cost threshold of parallelism setting
- Cpu pressure
- Worker queue length
- Execution plan

This investigation can take hours before I decide to make a change. What can I do in short term so the requests are not waiting for worker threads to be assigned?

We use SCOM to monitor many aspects of SQL Server and this is one of them. I understand this is more of a informational message but seeing is consistently from same server gives us opportunity to look at the things that I listed above. What I am trying to find out from the community, if they take certain action (can be temporary, till full evaluation is done) if `work_queue_count` is constantly greater than zero once alert is triggered by SCOM. There are times it is easy to detect a single query that is consuming lot of threads but not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default formula for [max workers] (at or below 64 logical CPUs): 16*(logical CPUs - 4) + 512

Here are two potential justifications if you want to raise [max workers]. If CPU is not saturated when DOP downgrades occur due to reserved worker count, negative consequences are limited. YMMV.

1. General: in sql server 2019 (maybe before? i’ve Not checked) if above 64 logical cpu/user schedulers, the multiplier for default is changed from 16 to 32. for the systems i care about, expected intensity of work per scheduler is the same whether 8 vcpu or 80. So why not always use 32?
2. specific to positioning re: hyperthreading.
   again, for my workloads, expected intensity of work *per core* is the same whether HT or not. But the VMs have 1 vcpu per pcpu. And some physical servers have HT disabled. In those cases, why not use the “theoretical” logical cpu/scheduler count for the system if HT were enabled?